# Change IMG src link inside PHP String

Tags: php, string, image, hyperlink, src

I'm facing trouble whereas the string I pulled from my database is like below

```
$string = 'The person name Abdul <img src="images/abdul.jpg" alt="abdul"/>.....';
```

that I need to change it to

```
$string = 'The person name Abdul <img src="../../images/abdul.jpg" alt="abdul"/>.....';
```

How do I solve this using PHP?

Comment: you should also consider using `DOMDocument for this. viable solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While not the most elegant solution and with many more out there, you could use PHP's `str_replace` and do something such as this.

```
<?php
   $string = 'The person name Abdul <img src="images/abdul.jpg" alt="abdul"/>.....';
   $string = str_replace('src="images/', 'src="../../images/', $string);

   echo $string;
?>
```

Note: The only reason I added `src="` infront of the images part is to help eliminate chances where an image may be misnamed. You could instead use this.

`$string = str_replace('images/', '../../images/', $string);`

I would recommend not saving items in a database as relative paths. Save just the image names or even better, the full URL of the image and echo it. It's cleaner and a more robust solution for large data (using CDNs, etc).

[More on `str_replace` here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: This settle my problem. Thanks RhapX

Answer (score 0):

Right way to do this, is **never to keep your DOM** inside your **DB**.

You can keep something like `##IMAGE_BASE_PATH##/adbul1.jpg` and when rendering the page in browser....

```
$image = str_replace('##IMAGE_BASE_PATH##','../../images', $string);
<img src="$image" />
```

(lot of ways to do this, above is one of them)

There are a lot of very good reasons for this. Some are:

- Reusing the data in another non-HTML context is not possible
- Extracting the data with other data joined to it is not possible
- You end up with encoding problems like you are having now
- If you wish to change the way your site is laid out, you have to update every database field, rather than just one HTML template.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9228734/1172872